# Can't download Gnome 3 for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: command-line, gnome

How can I install Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 12.10? I tried to `apt-get install gnome-panel`, but it errors out because of unmet dependencies, even if I pass `-f`:

```
kanha@kanha-Aspire-5580:~$ sudo apt-get -f install gnome-panel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-panel : Depends: libpanel-applet-4-0 (>= 3.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gnome-panel-data (= 1:3.6.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-applets but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-session-fallback but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: indicator-applet-complete but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard GNOME Shell, in addition to various core components and apps, are available in the default Ubuntu 12.10 software repositories. Most of the components are at version 3.6.*x*.

## Installing GNOME Shell

There are various methods of installing the GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 12.10:

### Without Adding Repositories

If you want to avoid adding additional software repositories, you can install the GNOME Shell from the default software sources. For just the Shell and default settings, go to Terminal (Control - Alt - T) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-default-settings;
```

If you want to use the GDM login manager, type:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm;
dpkg-reconfigure gdm;
```

Make sure to select GDM after typing the last command.

### Using the GNOME 3 PPA

If you want some more up-to-date components of the Shell, use the official GNOME 3 PPA. First, go to Terminal (Control - Alt - T) and add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3;
sudo apt-get update;
```

To install the shell, use the same instructions as the method above. You can use the instructions above to switch to GDM if you wish also.Then, you can upgrade all of your packages with software from the new repository with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
```

Make sure to keep your packages updated by running the last two commands often.

### The Complete Desktop

For very some extra components that are not available in the GNOME 3 PPA, you can use the GNOME 3 Staging PPA. Please beware that, although this repository contains some useful programs, contains primarily unstable software and has a high probability of breaking your system. Avoid using this on a production computer.

If you choose to continue, you can add the source and update your packages with the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
```

## Installing GNOME 3 Applications

The next step in attaining a complete GNOME 3 Desktop is installing the apps made for the GNOME Shell. Whether or not you have added any repositories, you can install the basic apps with the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-clocks gnome-software-manager gnome-boxes gnome-documents epiphany-browser gnome-tweak-tool evolution ubuntu-gnome-desktop;
```

If you want, you can install GNOME Shell Extensions at http://extensions.gnome.org.

Useful links:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html

Answer (score 1):

That message means that gnome 3 requires packages to work that apt-get isn't able to install, probably because they are not available in the default repositories. Which makes sense because gnome 3 isn't the default ubuntu desktop. Googling around tells me you have 2 choices -- either to install a Ubuntu 12.10 'remix' which comes with gnome 3 out of the box, or to install the required packages yourself, which looks to be but a matter of adding some repositories. Here is a tutorial I found but have not used: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html

Comment: The ubuntu remix and the second way require the same installation process ...